Сделать асинхронную программу многопоточной
Скрипты написаны асинхронно, но как сделать их многопочными, чтобы не запускать 10 терминалов, а один с 10 потоками?
from threading import Thread
import asyncio


async def test():
    print('start thread')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('stop thread')


async def main():
    for _ in range(5, 0, -1):
        thread = Thread(target=test)
        thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

возвращает ошибки
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback


Зачем вообще делать многопоточность в асинхронной программе?

При многопоточности вообще не нужен ни asyncio.run ни async. В простом случае пишется синхронный код, который где-то на старте разделяется на потоки. Но смысла в этом нет - этот код будет работать с такой же скоростью из-за GIL (тут конечно "зависит", но смысл в том, что при написании потоками с i/o-bound кодом будет одинаково, а с cpu-bound кодом с потоками контекст переключает планировщик, а с async вы сами). Вы просто смените одну модель синхронизации всего добра на другую, а в скорости не выиграете ничего.

Похоже решение - еще один скрипт, который запускает 10 терминалов другого скрипта))

"чтобы не запускать 10 терминалов" - ¿Зачем их запускать?

Решение - пул процессов. Внутри каждого процесса можно разделить на потоки или asyncio, если в этом есть смысл.

Для ускорения прогона скриптов, работаю с asyncpg для postgres, из бд забираю по 5к id и в каждом терминале работаю с ними

Для ускорения чего конкретно? Что мешает быстро делать асинхронную работу в одном потоке?

Получается, это проблема XY, задавайте вопрос про проблемы с производительностью, обязательно приводя [mcve].

Переписать на Mojo

@AlexanderPetrov что за глупости, если переписывать, то только на Rust

наверное стоит добавить больше контекста
Задача: написать скрипт, которые обращается к postgresql, забирает оттуда пачку id (5к), по каждому id выполняются запросы в graphql, grpc, все это выполняется асинхронно, до этого запускалось условно 15 терминалов, того 75к id, мутации асинхронные, без асинхронности там не обойтись

Ну да, многопоточность тут не нужна от слова совсем

vitidev, спасибо, что натолкнул на мысль
import time
import asyncio


async def test():
    print('начало')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('конец')


async def gen_tasks():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(3):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(test()))
    for task in tasks:
        await task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(gen_tasks())

ответ нашел здесь
Запуск несколько ассинхронных функций вместе на python

...и импортированный ProcessPoolExecutor никак не используется

извиняюсь, поспешил

Ну и в итоге никакой многопоточности тут всё равно нет, ну видимо и не нужна на самом деле)

async def gen_tasks():
await asyncio.gather(*(test() for _ in range(3)))

в python. Asyncio это не многопоточность. А конкурентное выполнение корутин на основе событийных циклов в одном потоке. В стандартном python вообще нет нормальных тредов из за GIL(Который собственно блокирует разделение контекста интерпретатора на треды). Реальный паралеллелизм в python возможен только на процессах, с своими минусами. См. multiprocessing.

прочитайте про отличия...
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism/


в вашем приложенном коде вы ничего не запускаете асинхронно. Попробуйте await asyncio.gather(*tasks) и без asyncio.create_task.

